# How can I obtain pixel value from map co-ordinate [longitude, latitude] for image of band count 1?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, pyproj, landsat

so I am using Landsat-8 image of band-4. I want to obtain the n-array index for given longitude and latitude values. I have tried below code

```
xs=np.array([92.8])
ys=np.array([26.6])
row,col=rasterio.transform.rowcol(src.transform,xs,ys)
print(row,col)
>>[99709] [-11627]     #output from the code
```

Output obtained is wrong because size of my image is (7791, 7651) and these values are out of index.
Can anyone please suggest me some changes to be made.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/358036/extracting-data-from-a-raster/358058#358058 ?

Comment: I tried this code but ' transformer.transform(lon, lat) ' returns ' inf, inf '

Comment: What happens when you add the err check=True kwarg?